# Show that this is an algebra-homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let V be a finite-dimensional k-vector space and let A be the algebra of linear transformations from V to V. Multiplication in A is composition of maps.

1) fix a linear transformation $\alpha$ of V. Check that the map:
$\phi$: from k[X] to A defined by $\phi(f)$ = $f(\alpha)$ is an algebra homomorphism.

I'm a little confused here, I suspect by a really fundamental issue. 
The hardest condition for the algebra homomorphism is showing that $\phi(f*g) = \phi(f)*\phi(g)$ right? But in K[X] isn't algebra-multiplication just multiplication of polynomials? and the RHS of $\phi(f)*\phi(g)$ is multiplication by composition so $\phi(f)*\phi(g)=f(\alpha)*g(\alpha)=f(\alpha(g(\alpha))))$ which is disgusting and obviously incorrect...
and the LHS of $\phi(f*g)$ is multiplication of the polynomials f and g in K[X] which means that $\phi(f*g)=(f*g)(\alpha)$

$\\
\\$
I suspect I don't know what the multiplication in one of the algebras is but I don't know where to find this information so any help would be appreciated.

$\\
\\
\\$

2) Now for the algebra $im(\phi)$. Describe a general element of $im(\phi)$. Also show that $ker(\phi))=(m(X))$ where m(X) is the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$. What can we say about the dimension of $im(\alpha)$?

Is a general element of $im(\alpha))$ like $\phi(f)=f(\alpha)$ which is basically a polynomial but with $\alpha(x)$ instead of $x$?

U have no idea about the next bits and I suspect I'm totally confused and don't know what's going on at all. I thought $ker\phi)$ is the set of f that get mapped to the zero polynomial? I don't know.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Please make it as simple to understand as possible as I'm new to this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

For 1) all you need to check is that $f(\alpha)\circ g(\alpha)=(f\cdot g)(\alpha)$. This isn't that strange, after all $\alpha\circ\alpha=\alpha^2$ ...

Also, note that $\alpha$ commutes with its powers.

For 2), as you said, $\ker\phi=(m(x))$ where $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Now apply the Isomorphism Theorem where the target ring is the (commutative!) $K$-algebra generated by $\alpha$ and think what the dimension of the ring $K[x]/(p(x))$ is when $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$.

Comment: would you mind giving me an exchange with a specific vector space and specific linear transofmration $\alpha$ and specific polynomials f and g?
like if $\alpha(x,y)=(x-1,y+2$ and $V=R^2$ and $g=x^2+2$ and $f=x^3+5x+1$ how does it work?

Comment: Mind that the $\alpha$ you wrote is *NOT* a linear transformation (doesn't send 0 to 0). In any event, whatever $\alpha$ you can think of, what is $(\alpha^2+2)\circ(\alpha^3+5\alpha+1)$ ? Besides, it should be clear that in the context of the ring of linear transformations, a constant $c$ actually means $c\cdot I$ where $I$ is the identity transformation/matrix.

Comment: oops, obviously it isn't a linear transofmration. you're right. apologies.
Is that just multiplication of (a^2+2)(a^3+5a+1)?

Comment: Recall that the composition and the sum of functions satisfy the distributive law. Thus, all boils down to checking that $\alpha^m\circ\alpha^n=\alpha^{m+n}$ for non-negative exponents, which should be rather obvious.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dumb here but:
$(\alpha^2+2)\circ(\alpha^3+5\alpha+1)=\alpha^5+5\alpha^3+\alpha^2+2\alpha^3+10 \alpha+2=(\alpha^2+2)(\alpha^3+5\alpha+1)=(x^2+2)(x^3+5x+1)(\alpha)$ $=(fg)(\alpha)$

which is what we want?

Comment: and I skipped a step in the first equals sign about what you said about with $\alpha^m\circ\alpha^n=\alpha^{m+n}$